# How do I copy and write a partition table from one identical disk to another?

Tags: linux, partitioning, raspberry-pi, sd-card

I've got several dozen Raspberry Pis that I use as part of a home lab experiment. I created an installation of Rasbian (the Pi-specific version of Debian) on one Pi, and I want to spread it to the rest of the Pis.

The Pis use MicroSD cards (of which all of the ones I purchased are the same 8GB capacity and the same model number). Previously, I was using dd to create an image of the "gold master" MicroSD card, but that takes a long, long time, as it makes the byte-for-byte image of the 8GB SD card and has to write it all (even though the total used space on the card is maybe 300 megs or less).

There are 3 partitions; a boot partition (with the kernel), a root filesystem partition (with the bulk of the OS), and a third special partition.

Rather than using dd, I was wondering if there was perhaps a way to copy the partition table to a file, write the partition table back to a new SD card, and then use my trusty rsync commands to copy just the data itself back to each partition.

Is this possible? Or am I better off just using parted and try and script that to replicate the partition tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Even tough you explicitly asked about "*...copy and write a partition table...*" I think you really want:

- to clone your gold-master image to other brand new, identical, SD-cards:
- to avoid "dd-ing" the whole 8GB source sd-card, as it contains only 300 MB of data.

In such a case there are alternatives to "dd", that can do exactly what you need: disk-cloning, but considering file-system properties/structure/boundaries.

One of such alternatives is **partimage** [1]: "*...It saves partitions having a supported filesystem on a sector basis to an image file [...] **Partimage will only copy data from the used portions of the partition**...*"

Please note that **partimage** can also be used in a client-server network environment and that it's included in several live-linux-CD, like **SystemRescueCD** [2]  (so to easier the process of cloning system disks).

Another tool you might want to check is **FSArchiver**.

---

[1] http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page

[2] http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage

---

*P.S.: sorry for not posting other relevant URLs but... this is my first answer and I cannot include more than 2 URLs*

Answer (score 3):

Sure – you can do that using `dd`. The MSDOS aka MBR partition table is in the first 512 bytes:

```
head -c 512 /dev/sdb > mbr.bin
cp mbr.bin /dev/sdc
partprobe

dd if=/dev/sde bs=512 count=1 of=mbr.bin
dd if=mbr.bin of=/dev/sdf
partprobe
```

However, this will not replicate the actual *filesystem* structure; you will have to run `mkfs` on the blank partitions anyway.

You might prefer scripting the `sfdisk` or `parted` tools to create partitions of specific sizes instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can speed `dd` up by increasing the block size with the `bs` flag.  I usually use the following: `dd if=/dev/source of=/dev/destination bs=8M`.  In all honesty, `dd` or `parted` are your best options, `dd` being the superior option for quality (in my opinion).

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but it should solve the problem

Comment: Be aware, that for some partition table types you can end up with two devices with the same UUID, which isn't a disaster, but also isn't ideal.  I always just copy it by hand.

Comment: Correct @rrauenza, however changing the UUID is usually simple using `blkid`, `uuidgen` and `tune2fs`. Example [here](http://www.sudo-juice.com/how-to-change-the-uuid-of-a-linux-partition/).  I'm sure there are cases where this will not work, but I have not encountered them yet.

Answer (score 1):

(A duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12986/how-to-copy-the-partition-layout-of-a-whole-disk-using-standard-tools)

I personally prefer not to use dd to avoid duplicating UUIDs.

Use sfdisk:

```
   -d, --dump
          Dump the partitions of a device in a format that is usable as input to sfdisk.  For example,
              % sfdisk -d /dev/hda > hda.out
              % sfdisk /dev/hda < hda.out
          will correct the bad last extended partition that the OS/2 fdisk creates.
```

Note this doesn't work with GPT -- but ...  you can use sgdisk instead:

```
sgdisk -R=/dev/sdb /dev/sda  # copy the table
sgdisk -G /dev/sdb           # randomize the GUIDs
```

Answer (score 0):

(I would have commented on @ray's answer above if I had enough rep)

If you are happy that the data is at the start of the SD card then just use `count` option of `dd`.

To add to @ray's example:

```
dd if=/dev/source of=/dev/destination bs=8M count=38
```

38 blocks of 8MB each is 304MB.  If you are using an intermediate file then this would be 304MB in size and when writing back you can omit the `count` option.

```
dd if=/dev/source of=~/intermediate_file bs=8M count=38
dd if=~/intermediate_file of=/dev/destination bs=8M
```

The intermediate file will have the added advantage that it will be quicker (assuming you save the intermediate file on a HDD or SSD) as there will be no slow reading from the SD card each time you clone.